# Kotlin - Invalid escape sequence: 0 when parsing to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, kotlin

i am trying to parse a big json file (>76K character) and read two regions out of it for mapping those into a WebView.

My problem is that i receive JSONExceptions when parsing it and i cant reconstruct the error.

This is my callVM class which includes the functionality.

```
fun callVM() 
    var url: String = getString(R.string.app_name)//R.string.myHtml


    try {
        //read url via getTermsString 
        url = getTermsString()

        val gson = Gson()
        var decodedHtml = unescape(url)
        readJson(decodedHtml)

        wv_map.loadData(decodedHtml, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("FAIL", "Initializing failed")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

The getTermsString()-function reads the "url", in this case its my api_response_jreal.json and no url. The naming is old.
The api_response_jreal.json is in my raw folder.

```
private fun getTermsString(): String {
    Log.e("gts", "Start getTermsString()")
    val ist: InputStreamReader

    try {
        Log.e("Reader", "Start reader")

        //R.raw.x - x equals the html file
        ist = InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.api_response_jreal))
        val theString = IOUtils.toString(ist)

        Log.e("gtsfin", "getTermsString() finished")
        ist.close()
        return theString
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        System.err.println(e.printStackTrace())
    }
    return "gts did not load anything."
}
```

My unescape function is there for replacing the escape character. I also tried to call the readJson-function without unescaping, but this is not working either...

```
 fun unescape(str: String) : String
{
    var strVar = str
    strVar = strVar
        // ADDED AFTER THE FIRST EXCEPTION.replace("\\u0","\\u003d")
        .replace("\\u003d","=")
        .replace("\\u003c","<")
        .replace("\\u003e",">")
        .replace("\\u0027","'")
        .replace("\\\"", "")
        .replace("\\t", "    ")
        .replace("\\u0023", "#")
        .replace("\\u0024", "$")
        .replace("\\u0025", "%")
        .replace("\\u0026", "&")
        .replace("\\u0028", "(")
        .replace("\\u0029", ")")
        .replace("\\u002A", "*")
        .replace("\\u002B", "+")
        .replace("\\u002C", ",")
        .replace("\\u002D", "-")
        .replace("\\u002E", ".")
        .replace("\\u002F", "/")
        .replace("\\u003A", ":")
        .replace("\\u003B", ";")
        .replace("\\u003F", "?")
        .replace("\\u0040", "@")
        .replace("/\\n/g", "\\n")
        .replace("/\\'/g", "\\'")
        .replace("/\\&/g", "\\&")
        .replace("/\\r/g", "\\r")
        .replace("/\\t/g", "\\t")
        .replace("/\\b/g", "\\b")
        .replace("/\\f/g", "\\f")
        .replace("\\s+", " ")
        .replace("\\\n","")
        .replace("\\n","")

    return strVar
}
```

Last but not least i try to transform my unescaped json to an Object to access the needed values (i just need "regionsToSvgMapping)

```
fun readJson(url : String){
    val data = JSONObject(url)
    Log.e("readjsn obj", "MyFile: " + data)
}
```

Now two exceptions appear.
The first was "Invalid escape sequence: 0"...
[image]

I copied the whole string in Notepad++ and take a look at character "3051"..

```
    <polygon id\u0
    03d12
```

Then i tried something stupid and thought the dumbest way would work and added the first .replace value in my unescape function. Well the dumbest way is not working ... ;)

Now its the time i dont have a solution for that problem and asking stackoverflow community.

I also tried to use a code beautifier to check if the json is complete so, this should be fine.

Thank you guys for help!

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to this issue, but assuming this is a new project you really shouldn't be using gson with kotlin, it does not play well with its constructors and null-safety, jackson (with kotlin module), moshi and kotlinx-serialization are all intended to be used with kotlin (and still under active development, unlike gson)

Comment: Have you tried to minimize json and reproduce the error? It would be helpful if you could share json that causes the problem.

Comment: `Invalid escape sequence: 0` points to the wrong character code `\0`. Why there is a line break after 0? Obviously it should be `\u003d` without line breaks. Is it so in the original json from server?

Comment: sorry for that late answer. 
I noticed that my escape string - Output are multiple strings. That means my .replace code returns multiple strings. 
I guess this is the problem here. I try to fix it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using StringBuilder.

When working with Strings >10k numbers and digits my Android studio has split the large string into multiple strings with around 1k numbers and digits.

To solve this i have used the stringbuilder like this,..

```
fun unescape(str: String) : String
{
    var stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var strVar = str
    strVar = strVar
        .replace("\\u003d","=")
        .replace("\u003d","=")
        .replace("\\u003c","<")
        .... (see above)

    stringBuilder.append(strVar)
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```